# Typescript variable type definition comment does not appear in tooltip/info

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums, comments

There is a status type

```
type Status = 'warning' | 'info' | 'error' | 'success';
```

My component has a prop that is of type status.

```
type MyComponentProps = {

/**
 * Description about status goes here.
 * Warning: definition of warning
 * Info: definition of info
 * Error: definition of error
 * Success: definition of success

**/
status: Status

}
```

Now, in this case the definition appears in a tooltip when you hover over the status prop inside my component.

I want to move these definitions up next to where `Status` is defined like this:

```
/*
 * Warning: definition of warning
 * Info: definition of info
 * Error: definition of error
 * Success: definition of success
 */

type Status = 'warning' | 'info' | 'error' | 'success';
```

```
type MyComponentProps = {

/**
 * Description about status goes here.

**/
status: Status;

}
```

But, now the info tooltip about type definition status does not show the definition for each status types. How can i fix it?

Comment: you need to set up a separate/emun variable first such as a regular one `type WarningStatus = 'warning`, type InfoStatus = 'info', and so on. At Status, you need to call: type Status = WarningStatus | InfoStatus | and so on.

Comment: Creating separate variable for constant strings will be an overkill, no?